# boot.ci error, due to too little variation in data?

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

I have a dataset of 79 values ranging from 0-22 (and not a lot of variation; median 5). Using the `boot.ci` function, I am trying to bootstrap to calculate confidence intervals. I receive the error: [1] "All values of t are equal to  5 \n Cannot calculate confidence intervals"

I assumed this is because my number of replications wasn't high enough (as there is little variation in the data), but increasing to even 1M doesn't help.

Does anyone have any tips?

```
Boot_symp_pres = boot(data$Delay,
                  function(x,i) median(x[i], na.rm=TRUE),
                  R=1000000)
boot.ci(Boot_symp_pres,
    conf = 0.95,
    type = c("norm", "basic" ,"perc", "bca"))
```

```
Data
   Delay
1 0
2 0
3 0
4 0
5 0
6 1
7 1
8 1
9 2
10 2
11 2
12 2
13 3
14 3
15 3
16 4
17 5
18 5
19 5
20 5
21 5
22 5
23 5
24 5
25 5
26 5
27 5
28 5
29 5
30 5
31 5
32 5
33 5
34 5
35 5
36 5
37 5
38 5
39 5
40 5
41 5
42 5
43 5
44 5
45 5
46 5
47 5
48 5
49 5
50 5
51 5
52 5
53 5
54 5
55 5
56 5
57 5
58 5
59 5
60 5
61 5
62 5
63 5
64 5
65 5
66 5
67 5
68 5
69 5
70 6
71 6
72 6
73 6
74 8
75 9
76 10
77 11
78 13
79 22
```

Comment: think about a simpler case: suppose your data were `rep(0:2, c(5,20,5))`.  In order for the median be different from 1 you'd have to sample >15 values=0 or >15 values=2, which would be *hugely* unlikely ...

Comment: True — thank you Ben.